# How to insert objects into std::vector?

Tags: c++, oop, object, stdvector

I am finding trouble inserting an object into a std::vector, following the example of what I'm trying to do:

*//in SomeClass.cpp*

```
void SomeClass::addItem(int32_t &position, OtherClass &value)
{
    vectorOtherClass.insert(position,valvalue);
}
```

however I get the following error when trying to compile the program:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector::insert(int32_t&, OtherClass&)’
>
> vectorOtherClass.insert(position,value);
>
> ______________________^

the vector definition in *SomeClass.h* is:

```
private:
    std::vector<OtherClass> vectorOtherClass;
```

How can I properly insert an object into a vector in C ++?

And one last question, are the objects stored by reference or by copy within the vector?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

You need to pass in an interator, so use begin and offset the position from there. *No need to pass in ints by ref unless your function is going to change them.* Consider checking for buffer overflow.

```
void SomeClass::addItem(int32_t position, const OtherClass &value)
{
    assert(position < vectorOtherClass.size());
    assert(position >= 0);
    vectorOtherClass.insert(vectorOtherClass.begin()+position, value);
}
```

Comment: Note that this is undefined behaviour if `position` is out of bounds, so it may be a good idea to also check `position >= 0` and `position <= vectorOtherClass.size()`

Comment: @M.M  Good point. I had made it but not as clearly saying "Consider checking for buffer overflow".  I've now added asserts to be very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error says, there is no insert function with int parameter. See:

```
single element (1)  
iterator insert (iterator position, const value_type& val);
fill (2)    
    void insert (iterator position, size_type n, const value_type& val);
range (3)   
template <class InputIterator>
    void insert (iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

You can find an example here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/

```
int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector (3,100);
  std::vector<int>::iterator it;

  it = myvector.begin();
  it = myvector.insert ( it , 200 );

  myvector.insert (it,2,300);

  // "it" no longer valid, get a new one:
  it = myvector.begin();

  std::vector<int> anothervector (2,400);
  myvector.insert (it+2,anothervector.begin(),anothervector.end());

  int myarray [] = { 501,502,503 };
  myvector.insert (myvector.begin(), myarray, myarray+3);

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (it=myvector.begin(); it<myvector.end(); it++)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I realized now that I misunderstood the vector in c ++. another doubt, when you use it + 2, are you making an insert in the second position of the vector?

Comment: Yes, for example:   std::vector<int> myvector (3,100);
  std::vector<int>::iterator it;

  it = myvector.begin();
  /* out: 100 100 100 */
  it = myvector.insert ( it , 200 );
  /* out: 200 100 100 100 */
  it = myvector.insert ( it+2 , 500 );
  /* out: 200 100 500 100 100 */

Answer (score 1):

According to [the method's reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/), the insert method takes the following parameters:

> `position`
>
> Position in the vector where the new elements are inserted.
>   iterator is a member type, defined as a random access iterator type that points to elements.
>
> `val`
>
> Value to be copied (or moved) to the inserted elements.
>   Member type value_type is the type of the elements in the container, defined in deque as an alias of its first template parameter (T).

Note that `position` is not an integral value, but rather an iterator. C++ use iterators a lot, since many operations are fairly efficient when you have one.

In particular, you can add vector iterators and numbers to get the iterator to the correct position, so you can do something like:

```
vectorOtherClass.insert(vectorOtherClass.begin() + position, value);
```

This does not apply to other containers such as `std::list`. Also, you should make sure to check `position` is within the bounds of the vector (`0 <= position < vectorOtherClass.size()`). Ideally, `position` should be unsigned to ensure the lower bound.

---

Lastly, elements are added to `std::vectors` as copies. Vectors use an array internally, so values are copied into it. The array is resized (copied and replaced) as needed.

Comment: As far as I understand with the comment of @jsn, when using the "vector::insert()" vector grows, however with your post I came to the understanding that the vector does not grow using "vector::insert ()", What is the correct result?

Comment: There's 2 separate things you should consider about vectors: size and capacity. Size represents the amount of elements stored in the container, i.e. an int vector of size 5 has 5 ints. Capacity has to do with the internal representation of the vector; the vector might have size 5 and capacity 10, which means no new allocations are required unless we add at least 6 new elements. At that point, the vector expands its capacity to accommodate the new elements, plus sum extra space to avoid future reallocations if possible. In short, insert always grows size, but only sometimes grows capacity.